# Bootstrap typeahead li click event

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap typeahead `li` click event is not firing. My code is:

```
<ul class="typeahead dropdown-menu" style="top: 43px; left: 576.5px; display: none;">
    <li class="tyli" data-value="Thana Thana">
    <li class="tyli active" data-value="Thiline Lesin">
    <li class="tyli" data-value="Thani Taruwe">
    <li class="tyli" data-value="Thotupala Aine">
    <li class="tyli" data-value="Tharu Wiyane">
    <li class="tyli" data-value="Tholata Mala">
    <li class="tyli" data-value="Thaama Tharunai">
    <li class="tyli" data-value="Thana Thinane">
</ul>
```

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click','li', function (){     
    alert('Hello');     
});
```

List is dynamic and it will appear after page load.
My javascript code added after page load.

Any thing wrong here?

Comment: how about making a fiddle and/or adding your html and javascript code in the question?

Comment: hi webdad3 ,my code edited.

Comment: do what Cerebus1504 suggests.  Go to getbootstrap.com.  There are loads of examples there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a suitable example for you to start. If u wanna work on bootstrap, getbootstrap.com will more than helpless

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->

    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Sample</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Portfolio <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="portfolio-1-col.html">1 Column Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="portfolio-2-col.html">2 Column Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="portfolio-3-col.html">3 Column Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="portfolio-4-col.html">4 Column Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="portfolio-item.html">Single Portfolio Item</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="blog-home-1.html">Blog Home 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="blog-home-2.html">Blog Home 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="blog-post.html">Blog Post</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other Pages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="full-width.html">Full Width Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="sidebar.html">Sidebar Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="404.html">404</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing Table</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- JavaScript -->

</body>

</html>
```